# how to remove foreign architecture on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, 23.04

when I tried to upgrade it is shown as follows:-unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
ub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-n
How can I solve this?